# Fastest way to send logs from Kafka to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, go, apache-kafka, rsyslog

I am looking for the **fastest** log shipper which can directly transfer my logs to elasticsearch from kafka.
I can name some ways to do this:

1. Kafka -> Elasticsearch
2. Kafka -> Logstash -> Elasticsearch
3. Kafka -> Golang ->  Elasticsearch
4. Kafka -> rsyslog -> Elasticsearch
5. Kafka -> java/c/c++ -> Elasticsearch ...

Can someone tell me which is the fastest way (Highest EPS with the same resource) to do the job?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey @Le, I believe what you are looking for is [Kafka Connect Elasticsearch Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/index.html#quick-start). Also, read up on how you can ask objective and crisp questions at [Help Center > Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to be more effective around here :)

Answer (score 1):

*Fastest* is kinda hard to say; there are several good options and it's going to come down to factors including your hardware, message size, and so on.

For any integration in and out of Kafka, my starting point is always Kafka Connect—since it's part of Apache Kafka itself. There is a [connector for Elasticsearch](https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/) which you can download standalone for use with an existing Kafka Connect cluster, or indeed obtain as part of Confluent Platform.

*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent.*

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently trying rsyslog. It's simple but quite hard to use because of unclear documents.